# How to check if thread is running or completed using swift

Tags: ios, iphone, multithreading, swift

I'm really do not know how to check .. whether a thread is alive or not in swift.

In my case, on button click event I'm creating new thread and also starting a NSTimer object. At regular interval i need to check if thread is alive or not.
So how do i check if thread is alive or not.

```
var objDS= DeviceStatus()
let thread = NSThread(target: objDS, selector: "checkDeviceStatus", object: nil)
```

If possible please provide a example or some reference link.

thanks,

Comment: How you created thread ? Can you add any relevant code ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can determine it through the Thread’s execution state properties

**executing**

```
var executing: Bool { get } // true if the receiver is executing, otherwise false.
```

**finished**

```
var finished: Bool { get } //true if the receiver has finished execution, otherwise false.
```

**cancelled**

```
var cancelled: Bool { get } //true if the receiver has been cancelled, otherwise false.
```

Example:

```
var objDS= DeviceStatus()
let thread: NSThread = NSThread(target: objDS, selector: "checkDeviceStatus", object: nil)

if thread.executing{
    println("executing")
}

if thread.finished{
    println("finished")
}

if thread.cancelled{
    println("cancelled")
}
```

Comment: One thing, make sure to specify the type in declaration "let thread: NSThread = NSThread(...)